# How to assign to a list in R without creating a bunch of new elements?

Tags: r

If I say `l = list()` and then I do `l[[27]] = 100`, it will create 26 other entries with the value `NULL` in them. Is there a way to avoid this?

For example if I run: `l <- list(); for (i in c(4,7,1)) { l[[i]] <- i^1 }`

It will creat a list with entries ranging from 1 to 7, and NULL values for all the ones I did not assign. How can I avoid these spurious entries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use character values for the indices:

```
l <- list(); for (i in c(4,7,1)) { l[[as.character(i)]] <- i^1 }

> l
$`4`
[1] 4

$`7`
[1] 7

$`1`
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid a `for` loop and use `lapply`:

```
> x <- c(4, 7, 1)
> setNames(lapply(x, `^`, 1), x)
$`4`
[1] 4

$`7`
[1] 7

$`1`
[1] 1
```

Comment: Josh commented that you could also do `setNames(as.list(x^1),x)`. Yes, that would work here and is worth mentioning, thanks. Mine is more general in the sense that a non vectorized function can be applied.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I deleted my query: I realized you were adressing the more general situation!

Answer (score 0):

You could append to the list:

```
l <- list(); for (i in c(4,7,1)) { l <- append(l, i^1) }
```